# Unanswered Questions - inactive users

Tags: discussion, answers, accepted-answer, unanswered-questions

Is there anyway that we can as a community can handle unanswered questions? I'm like many here a bit of a perfectionist and in an ideal world we'd have every question on the site either closed or answered. Unfortunately the world isn't ideal.

What is frustrating though, is when you (and others) have put effort into answering a question - even responding to follow up questions, and then the original asker goes quiet. As a particular example [Dictionary enumeration in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/676880/dictionary-enumeration-in-c-sharp/676885#676885) the user seemed inactive for about a year after asking this question when he asked another one, and then a few months later asked a final question.

I find it a bit of a kick in the teeth when I've put effort into answering a question, and no one's answer gets selected - I know it's not many rep points, but this site is built all around gamification and I enjoy getting accepted answers - it's what drives me to contribute.

So I'm wondering if there's anything that can be done specifically for low rep/inactive users who aren't as interested in the community and leave these questions marked as unanswered when there are answers that fit the original question?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

What would you have us do, send a hit-squad to the user *forcing* them to participate?

No, there isn't anything (reasonable) that we can do. If you did it right, your answer is helpful to *other people* too and you'll get upvotes, over time.

Marking an answer as accepted is exclusively the right of the original asker; there is no point in applying community voting to the accepted answer because the community *already* votes on your question with the up- and down-arrows. Voting *again* for the accepted mark is pointless then.

Comment: The community tend to vote on such matters (when edits are required, questions need closing). The ability to vote on answers to inactive questions would be one approach.

Comment: I do like you're point about the upvotes helping others though - you're correct there

Comment: [If we're willing to do it for pluralization bug reports](https://twitter.com/codinghorror/status/1165936105), why not for inactivity.

Comment: @Ian: to mark an answer as accepted? No, because that is exclusively the right of the question asker. That's been discussed to death before.

Comment: A long term problem is duplicate questions. You can't close a duplicate unless the previous question has an accepted answer. You could copy the same answer and get it accepted on the new question but that might bypass the whole discussion that happened on the original question.

Comment: @HackSlash: what has that got to do with *accepting* an answer? And if you already posted an answer to a question and then found it to be a duplicate of a question with no answer, another option is to close the old question as a duplicate of the new. Provided the new question is of better quality that's perfectly acceptable.

Comment: I'm talking about a question that does have a highly rated question that cannot be accepted because the OP is gone. Now we get duplicate questions that are similar to the old one. I go to close as duplicate but I can't because the authoritative answer is in an "unanswered" question. Maybe there should be an exception made for user accounts that are deleted.

Answer (score 4):

There is nothing whatsoever wrong with a question asker not accepting an answer to a question, even if you think that there is a good answer.  There is nothing to change about the system.  If members of the community feel that an answer is helpful they can upvote it.

Answer (score 4):

Users answering old questions typically get very little love both from the asker (who probably disappeared) and from other upvoters (who either don't care – or they would have answered – or don't see the updates at all).

IMHO such altruists should get some incentives, like a [gold badge for revival/necromancer pattern](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/254753/248268) (which I proposed to call **Persephone**).

The key issue is that awarding reputation or badges for answers which were not double-checked by anyone is easy to game, but rewarding a *pattern* (as Socratic does) requires more effort and is less liable to unpunished gaming.

Comment: In this case this was not an old question. It was a new question but the user has since abandoned it (and the site) so never had an answer marked. Stops me being my silver badge :(

Comment: @Ian, I guess "old" is relative. Some people use SO as a place which produces them an answer in minutes, saving them the effort to think.

Comment: Bumping this! Even if we can't an alternative to accepting the question, we need more incentives for old questions. Perhaps bonus points on bounties?