# Old forgotten questions

Tags: discussion, questions, answers, old-questions

What happens to old questions with answers that never get accepted, but don't get any more answers or activity? Do they just hang out on the site getting more and more forgotten? They're usually asked by newer users who probably don't know that you should accept the answer that has solved the issue. This isn't really an issue I guess, but I was just wondering if there's something in place for this type of question.

Comment: Keep in mind that the checkmark doesn't mean "solved". It means "this answer helped me the most". In theory an OP could argue: *This answer is so bad that it showed me clearly where I screwed up. For that reason this answer helped me the most, have the checkmark* ... unlikely to happen often but it isn't ruled out either.

Comment: My top scoring [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1433204/how-do-i-use-extern-to-share-variables-between-source-files/1433387#1433387) with over 1800 upvotes is not accepted — and the OP is no longer active on the site so it never will be accepted.  It happens; it doesn't mean that the answer is of no value (I think; I hope!).

Comment: "Do they just hang out on the site getting more and more forgotten" - this happens to accepted answers too.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I'm still scrolling... ;-)

Comment: I don't even use that feature, because I think it's very wrong that accepted answers gets pinned on the top.

Comment: @klutt Accepted answers shouldn't get pinned to the top, but accepting an answer does provide a greater reward to those spending their precious time helping you.

Comment: After some delay and a high rate of acceptance upon the community, any best answer should be automatically accepted.

Comment: @s.k `high rate of acceptance upon the community` - Upvotes?

Comment: @Thomas — finished yet?  It's long, but it does tell you when to stop if you're not an experienced or interested C programmer.

Comment: @QHarr yes, that was was I meant, indeed. Do you see something else? Or any clever combination of, for example, upvotes / positiveness of the votes / views?

Comment: @NotThatGuy Correction. It provides a greater reward to ONE of those who helped you.

Comment: @s.k Why should they be automatically accepted?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The following is about open questions with at least one answer but no [accepted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234) one and without the OP's account having been deleted:

1. They will **not** be auto-deleted by [Roomba](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221) due to the answer.
2. No one but the OP can accept an answer (there have been so far unsuccessful [feature requests](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/275594/11682469) trying to change it)
3. They might be [bumped](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/48578) by the Community User under some circumstances.

These questions stay on the site and the solutions might help other visitors. New answers can also be added.

Comment: At least post about accepting answers, has an accepted answer. Nice!

Comment: "without the OP's account having been deleted" - does this change anything about what happens to such questions? I only see one minor difference for deleting old questions (<=1 score instead of <=0 score), but this only applies to unanswered questions.

Comment: @NotThatGuy I added that because of bullet points 12 and 13 in the FAQ. 12: "The system will automatically delete any post with a negative score when its owner's account is deleted, unless the post is an open question that has at least one positively-scored answer, or is on a meta site."

Comment: Number 2 sounds very reasonable for inactive accounts, though perhaps not inactive questions. Perhaps via vote-based consensus? Thanks for pointint out previous feature requests, gonna have to look into it!

Answer (score 4):

A question does not become “forgotten” just because it does not have an accepted answer. Look at this list:

https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=hasaccepted%3A0

And at the same time, there are lots of “forgotten” questions with accepted answers.

But if your questions is if they ever will get an accepted anwser, the answer is: No. At least probably not. And definitely not unless OP accepts it.

Comment: It has happened that an Answer on a years old Question gets accepted. It's not common, but it happens.

Comment: I've had an OP accept my answer 2.5 years after posting, and once I even had one remove my accept in order to accept their low-quality self-answer after 3 years.

Comment: @AndrasDeak Say what? Link?

Comment: I don't think it shows up in any timeline, but [this answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33192291/5067311) posted in October 2015 was accepted on March 22 2018. I don't want to link the other one to protect the mostly innocent.

Comment: @AndrasDeak: It is not inconceivable that they found their self-answer more helpful to them than your answer, even if your answer is _generally_ better.

Comment: @einpoklum well yeah. Most people are not malicious, merely ignorant.

Comment: #NecropostsMatter