# How should we react with users who ask questions without any responsiveness or feedback however they have some other activities on SO?

Tags: discussion, unanswered-questions

This question is relatively similar to some other questions: [1](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/119197/problem-with-users-not-accepting-answers), [2](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/262672/13394817), and [3](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/275594/unanswered-questions-inactive-users). I have faced to some issues on SO which are asked, but their authors leave no feedback at all (up/down-vote, accept or comment) for the proposed comments and answers. It is perceptible for new users or for aged questions which were asked long time ago and may be impossible for the author to check it (that we believe write the true answer [e.g. see SO issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69889294/13394817)).

This issue is about new asked questions, that we tried and spent time to answer but the author didn't react to any answers or comments at all; By tracing their activities we realize that ***they are active on SO*** (e.g. they asked another question or answered on another post after that question). **Just** for an example, I refer to [this user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17897456/mateo-vial?tab=activity) which I answered and placed some comments on his two questions ([Q1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71556243/13394817), [Q2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71549829/13394817)). I put some comments to ask him about his further needs too, but no reaction. As it is shown in his SO activity page, ***they were active after my answers*** but has no reaction. Also, by seeing [his SO question page](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17897456/mateo-vial?tab=questions) we realize that ***they didn't accept any answers so far on their previous questions***, just very few reactions on them. I think, if an asker found their answer themselves, they must inform others to avoid wasting their time.

How should we react to such users or their posts on the SO if we faced to (**just** for guiding for better behavior; not downvoting or …)?

Did SO set any limits or restrictions for such behaviors?

Something like "*moderators or … certainly judge if the OP has given sufficient feedback (or any at all) to those who are posting answers.*" which is mentioned by **RTbecard comment** on [this discussion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/262672/13394817).

** The mentioned posts or users in this question are not pointed for any revenge.

Comment: Just move along, maybe they're busy, maybe the question is no longer helpful to them, maybe somebody stole their keyboard, who knows.

Comment: "he was active after my answers but has no reaction" - and what would we do about that? Threaten to suspend? Find out where they live and make them? Continued interaction with a question is actually not required, and it's something that's not possible to enforce anyway.  People some times don't accept or upvote answers. It happens. Just move on and don't worry about it. At the end of the day, it's only imaginary internet points.

Comment: @RobertLongson, I will continuedly use SO, so I think it is not wasting my time if I ask to know how to act. I do not have any problem with any particular person, I did not downvote any issues which are asked by that person who I mentioned. I think this will prove my honesty.

Comment: @NickstandswithUkraine,  Dear Nick, I talk about users who are asking questions, but letting them go. The mentioned user, **I emphasize just for example**, did not accept any answers so far and most of the time did not respond to any questions that answerer asked. Indeed, the spent time by the answerers would be better to be guided to devote to persons that needs answers or have problems. I think writing something like 'it is solved' or …, can do it in a second, (if the keyboard is not stolen yet, on the fly during rescue).

Comment: @Ali_Sh since we are not a forum, writing "solved" is explicitly discouraged. Contrary to a belief popular amongst question askers, their posts are not help requests but are rather contributions to the knowledge base. Even if the problem is thrice solved, it does not matter.

Comment: As for the responsiveness problem, unfortunately, that's a fact of life. It does not help that SE does little to make users understand that we are not a help desk. So the best advice here is to pick and choose questions to answer (if user responsivenss is important to you). On an off-note, if a given question requires clarifications from the asker, flag (vote after 3K rep) to close as "needs details or clarity" - with the volume of questions on SO, the onus is on the asker to provide as much info as ppssible if they want an answer.

Comment: @ZoestandswithUkraine, "Find out where they live and make them?" :). I have answered lots of questions which didn't get any feedback with the authors. There is no problem with them, just for who repeated this behavior many times. Perhaps an automatic massage (like something hidden based on a ration between users questions and accepted answers) for bettering his question or a click button (if he don't want to answer or have no time to answer himself) to inform others in his next online time or ….

Comment: @OlegValteriswithUkraine, Thanks for your comments. I put an idea in the previous comment to Zoe. I am not a SO expert or moderator to know what could be done in this regard, if possible. But, I think, something that can handle this issue, will be helpful. "if user responsiveness is important to you" was not my main objective of this question, by itself, as I explained above. I think I have stated badly (I am not native in English) that leads others to comment a bit aggressively.

Comment: @Ali_Sh well... It's a complicated matter. There used to be a publicly available "accept rate", it went [as well as one would imagine](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/272890/11407695) (users harassed over their score). Plus there is a notification shown to low-rep users about remembering to vote if I recall correctly. There's also tour and the help center, but askers usually don't bother with either. The system *could* encourage interactions by sending reminders to users who seemingly abandoned their questions, and that idea *does* have merit, IMO, but that is a discussion in itself.

Comment: As for the importance of user responsiveness - it was a general note to the "pick and choose" advice me and others have given ("you" here is generic). Unless SE radically changes their approach to how they advertise SO for new users, there is little that can be done to improve the responsiveness, and you are better off just not interacting with posts you have a feeling the user will never return to (again, if that's actually important to you, as many, including me, don't particularly care if a user ever returns, it's the future readers that really matter).

Comment: @OlegValteriswithUkraine, I agree with your comments. I pointed in my comment that something like *acceptance rate* must be ***hidden***, just for evaluating to sending something like encouraging massage to the authors.

Comment: @Ali_Sh I know, I know - I was just listing examples of various projects related to voting/acceptance metrics/nudging. Tocbe completely honest, I would not support accept rate in any form - the accept checkmark is a relic from support forums and really needs to bite the dust. But more nudging for voting by the system - sure, all for it, as it actually performs a very useful task: rating content.

Answer (score 2):

While you should not target users with actions, it is perfectly fine (and encouraged) to "target" users with inaction on your side. If you for whatever reason, feel that interactions with the author will not be positive for you it is better to skip the post/comment and move on to other posts.

It looks like acceptance and otherwise interactions from the author of a question are important for you - information about this particular user's actions is public and you can check it out before interacting with the question. Note that commenting about "not accepting answer" or "not interacting" is not advised - please keep *your* interactions to be about the given question or answer and not the user who posted it when you decided to interact with the post.

Note so that neither accepting an answer nor responding to comments is required from authors of posts/comments. The content is there to serve future visitors - and question are there to invite great answers to achieve the goal of helping future visitors see [optimize for pearls](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/06/13/optimizing-for-pearls-not-sand/) by Jeff Atwood.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. IMO, searching and finding users who interact or have a good acceptance rate by the answerers is not the right thing to do, at least for me. However, IMO, SO is better to consider something like that mentioned in the comments with *OlegValteriswithUkraine* and *me*. I think, such things (encouraging massage and/or a button on the issue to click by the author if he found the answer himself or …) can improve the SO efficiency. I disagree with some comments on the question which are saying post your answer and leave it  unfinished just by some notes that may be not related.

Comment: SO could utilize an AI or something like that to suggest **all** posts or contents that may be related to the main searched question for future visitors, if it be one of the main SO goals. I ask you, is not it better if the author found his answer warn other answerers to guide them to other questions if they have limited time to contribute on SO to answer new questions??