# Put a points premium on unanswered questions?

Tags: feature-request, reputation, bounty, unanswered-questions

I'd like to make a suggestion that we put a points premium on the unanswered questions on SO. Maybe every 30 days we += the point value. So after 30 days, answers are worth 20 points, after 60 days, 40 points, after 90 days 80 points, etc.

Also, for moderators at a high enough level to mark as answered if it's obvious that it was the correct answer (maybe the original poster doesn't know SO enough to mark it, or they have moved on?).

I know that personally, I often feel that many of those old questions are just not worth my time. Putting a points premium might change my attitude. Probably many other members would feel the same way.

Comment: Sounds like a bounty, and only the author should have marking for correct.

Comment: Welcome to meta.SO, please lurk more (and search more). The "let mods/community mark an answer as accepted" part of your feature request is something that regularily pops up here and is regularily declined, see e.g. [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/262672/1110381) and the linked posts there. The other part, increasing rep for answers to older posts, sounds contraproductive in many ways. For example, as people are quick to upvote anything that remotely sounds like an OK answer, I could forsee people posting crap answers to tons of old questions to farm some drive-by votes.

Comment: Maybe for questions that go unanswered for a period of time, we could remove the mark-as-answer capability from the original poster, and only let a moderator-level do this? That would filter out the crap answers, I think. And hopefully help bring answers to the old questions. Not all questions go old because they're crap. They just represent too much effort for a member to answer for a measly 10 points. Which they can get by posting an off-the-cuff answer to other, more active posts.

Answer (score 10):

This is what [the bounty system](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work) is for.  To attract attention and good answers to unanswered questions, offer bounties on them.

Increasing the point value on old questions would almost certainly cause some people *not* to answer them, in hopes of getting more points later. While enough others would probably answer to offset that gaming, askers would be deprived of answers..

Comment: It would also incentivize people to answer old, bad questions, that should be deleted, not answered.

Comment: The bounty system is restricted. An infrequent user who posts a valid but hard-to-answer question won't be able to offer much of a bounty. It's not realy incentivizing. And asking for a random person to offer up a bounty out of the goodness of his/her heart doesn't seem to be working for these old questions, either.