# How do you go about accepting an answer for an excavated question?

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer

In long search of advice on how to accomplish something with a logging framework I found the exact question I needed answered: [How to include Log4j2 messages in TestNG reporting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26482861)

Alas; no one has viewed the question in quite some time. Needing an answer to it, I posted a bounty on the question and got my answer.

I feel the question has been adequately answered and I have manually awarded the bounty. I do not think the poster is going to approve an answer anytime soon and I thought it would be nice to award the answer to the person who gained the bounty.

So boiled down... can an admin or anyone accept the answer on behalf of the user, mark it as answered or do we simply have to wait and hope?

Comment: No, this is [not possible](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262672/can-moderators-make-an-answer-accepted-to-close-the-post). Only the user who asked the question can mark an answer as accepted.

Comment: Your bounty gave the answerer more rep than the accept checkmark ever would have. The answerer is likely quite happy with their reward.

Answer (score 7):

> can an admin or anyone accept the answer on behalf of the user,

Nope!

And as requested many times before, won't be implemented.

---

The accept is a privilege solely present to the questioner of a question, and to let them decide what helped them most to solve their problem.

That's it's only purpose, and totally independent of better answers provided from a more generic point of view.

---

The accept mark doesn't really provide significance for the accepted answer, since the OP usually is the least experienced person to judge about that.