# Shouldn't there be a feature which allows removal of green tick?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Maybe there is such a feature. I found few questions which were marked as the correct answers, but due to broken backward compatibility or maybe due to recent developments there is a better answer to the question.

Specific Question: [Can RDP clients launch remote applications and not desktops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1226772/can-rdp-clients-launch-remote-applications-and-not-desktops)

Comment: This might be a variation to the question: Is OP the right person to accept the answer?

Comment: The OP the only person who can, (sanely), accept the answer.  I cannot think of any other mechansim that would not result in open warfare, (probably thermonuclear, resulting in SO extinction).

Comment: I accept that there are, occasionally less-than-optimal answers accepted. Some answers are upvoted and accepted even though they cannot possibly work correctly, [multithreaded tag, usually:].   That is a price we should pay for overall, (mostly), sanity:)

Comment: @MartinJames My whole point is shouldn't we be able to correct wrongly accepted answers. Why compromise?
This could work based on some sort of democracy (More points to answer becomes accepted by default?) or meritocracy (users who have more points have these powers); Just a thought (:

Comment: see also: [Can moderators make an answer accepted to close the post?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/262915/839601)

Answer (score 10):

Accepted answer are not the only useful answers. They are accepted by the user who asked the question, and not by other users.

It doesn't make sense to me if other users could "tick" answer instead of OP. Why would we want to allow such a thing? If you think the link is dead, or the answer is not useful anymore, comment and maybe downvote. This will help other users.

Regarding that specific question, the link was fixed by earlier edit.

Comment: Green tick are misleading in case the answer is not useful or wrong in present context. I would read the comments, only after I have tried the accepted answer and it does not work; Which honestly is waste of time.

Comment: @spetzz I do the opposite - I first read the comments, and only then consider using the answer. For me it's not a waste of time, I learn a lot from comments.

Comment: I guess, I will have to follow your method. But I would still argue that since, Answer is most visible part of the page and comments are hidden, UX favors misleading the user

Comment: @spetzz accepted answer only means that "it's the most helpful answer **for the asker**", that's all. It could (and should) probably be helpful to others, but that's not always the case. That's why as Maroun has mentioned, it doesn't make sense to remove the tick without OP's approval (unless it's an obvious abuse, but that's not the case here). Anyway, without the tick, that answer will still be on the top since it has the highest score.