# How to get an accepted answer to be unaccepted

Tags: discussion, specific-question, accepted-answer

I stumbled over this post yesterday searching for something related to named ranges, [Excel Combine Named Range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27043085/excel-combine-named-range/27043353#27043353). I read the answer and saw a load of comments below it, curiously I read those as well. Then I read this comment by OP:

> Thanks @USERXYZ * - ignore my last message, what you have written makes sense. I have realised that this doesn't work for me is due to the fact that CityLocation is a dynamic named range, which seemingly don't work with the INDIRECT function. I'll accept the answer though as I didn't make this clear in the question.

This comment invalidated the answer, however OP decided to accept the answer none the less. I thought this was bad behaviour so I was looking for a way to get the answer unaccepted, as it doesn't solve the question. I decided to raise a custom flag on it, as that was the best way I could think of.

Apparently a mod decided that this wasn't the appropriate way, as the flag got declined. Fair enough.

So my question is, what would be the appropriate mode of action in this case?

---

*anonymised username

Comment: While [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/262915/957731) deals with having someone else accept an answer if there are none, I think the arguments there fit this just as well. The take-away is that the check mark is not there to indicate correctness but to indicate what the asker found *most useful*. Only they can decide that.

Comment: The OP sputters a bit, but only because he realized he asked the wrong question.  Thankfully he did not edit the question and invalidate the answer.  Don't mess it up please, if you need the answer to the real question (albeit hard to see) then just click the Ask Question button.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, leave it be.

While the answer addresses the problem as outlined in the question, it seems to fail on OP's actual data/system because of reasons/details that were not mentioned in the question. The important thing to note here is the answer *does* answer the question in its full capacity, and details that were not mentioned in the problem are, well, irrelevant. And besides, votes decide the merit of an answer, not the check mark.

The best thing to do here would be to have the comment thread deleted, since it does not appear to be constructive to the discussion.

Comment: Well said _votes decides the merit of an answer, not the check mark_

Comment: Unfortunately, I just found an answer that was accepted in 2018 and also has 4 upvotes. Not only does the solution not compile but it doesn't work when the corrections are made.  And those corrections don't impact the overall logic of the solution.