# Is this improper behavior? -- OP: "I have not verified the solution as I had to give up on what I was doing."

Tags: discussion, questions, accepted-answer

TL;DR: **Where to draw the line between users freedom and site guidelines when it comes to taking the time to verify a proposed answer?** (given it is the only answer provided, and not long after the question was open)

This is not a discussion about enforcing answer acceptance (e.g. for the sake of earning some reputation), but rather about better understanding users freedom VS site guidelines.

---

It happened to me recently, after suggesting an answer to a rather interesting question, getting no feedback from OP, and finally asking through comment if the problem was solved, that OP answered something like:

> I have not verified the solution as I had to give up on what I was
>   doing.

(I am not sure sharing the exact question/comment would be meaningful)

I understand that [it doesn't make sense to "enforce" answer acceptance](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/262915/624547). The quality/usefulness of an answer is also, if not mostly, evaluated by the rest of the community.
On the other hand, it is mentioned in the [guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) that:

> If someone posts an answer, be ready to try it out and provide feedback!

Hence the aforementioned question. Where to draw the line between users freedom not to accept/verify every answer, and the site guidelines? Are there *bad* reasons not to provide feedback (e.g. "I don't have time for this project anymore", while opening new threads)? If yes, what should one do to point this out?

Comment: Wanted now: Stack Overflow Enforcers. Visiting you at home or workplace making sure you do the right thing.

Comment: How old was the question when you answered it? I interpret the site rules more as "If you want to get help, be ready to try out answers and provide feedback." I don't read into it that you have to tryout every answer posted to your question for all times.

Comment: @yivi what's the pay?

Comment: @yivi I learned that Jeff is also no longer welcome to [pay you a house visit](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/63791/158100). I'm not sure if those enforcers are welcoming enough ...

Comment: @Script47 Pretty sure we'd find users available to do it for free if we ask around in meta...

Comment: @rene It's the other way around: People should be more welcoming towards the enforcers (they are comming to their house after all)

Comment: @rene Ok, I guess the Enforcer team cannot bludgeon users to death... I imagine that will make some users withdraw their application, but I do think that would be over the top and certainly not welcoming.

Comment: No bludgeoning? Pfft, I'll pass.

Comment: I've had answers come in months after I asked about something and I've been in situations where I no longer work with the tech or on the project using it any more. I don't personally feel like I need to go back and verify something in that case.

Comment: @ivarni: To give some context, The answer was given 4h after the question had been asked and is the only answer. I think if you post to SO, you should at least be interested in the answer for a few hours. Otherwise you shouldn't have posted at all.

Comment: The vast majority of questions on SO are about problems that the OP created by himself.  Digging himself into a deep hole by trying to solve the problem the wrong way.  If your answer made that clear to him, it often does even without explicitly saying so, then that is a good result as well.  But sure, not one that likely can be accepted.  The OP is doing the Right Thing.

Comment: @BDL Absolutely, but since the question didn't contain any information about the time frame I commented from a general perspective.

Comment: But if we can agree that 4 hours is too short to lose interest in a question and 2 months are too long, do we really want to keep narrowing down what an acceptable limit is?

Comment: I would rather they were honest about not verifying the solution than accepting it just to keep the poster happy.

Comment: (I am a bit disconcerted by the reception my discussion thread got... I did my research and thought I was taking a different angle from other related threads, but am I actually duplicating? How should my post be improved otherwise? Or should I understand it would be better to delete it? The latter seems like a pity to me given the interesting answers... Meta-newbie I guess...)

Comment: @Aldream, Vote is different on meta. It's basically a yes / no vote. And don't be disconcerted , we know the feeling. We all encounter vanishing OP. We have all spend time in an answer trying to solve an issue without even a little aknowledgement. I hope at least one of us manage to make you smile as we can't do anything.

Comment: @Aldream Don't delete meta posts. Especially if they have interesting discussion / answers.

Comment: @Aldream you can't delete it, it has upvoted answers. It is not a duplicate, at least not of the question it was closed against (which is why I re-opened it). In general, most *behavior* questions struggle on meta, specially if it seems you would possible benefit if the behavior is indeed unwanted. But it is hard to discuss anything if you don't point out an existing example. No winners in that battle.

Comment: @DragandDrop (aka Care_Bear_01? ;) ) I got votes work differently here, but I thought [it was for `feature-request`, not `discussion`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/254113/624547). The `yes`/`no` meaning would make sense here. Thanks!

Comment: Yes it's for feature-request, and no one will use upvote/downvote to show acceptance outside of that tag.

Comment: @rene Right, I did forget about the can't-delete-if-upvoted-answers rule (not that I wanted to in any case, 'was just wondering if it was something _expected_ from me). Thanks for the explanations too! My point was not to point the finger at the OP who got me thinking about the whole problem, though indeed a more concrete example could have helped the discussion maybe...

Comment: @Aldream no worries, to me it certainly didn't read that way which is why I was happy to post an answer. Now if you can please accept my answer, we can move on. Unless you're no longer interested in the answer ...  ;)

Comment: @rene Hehe, what if I want to exercise my right to let this thread remain unanswered? Slightly more seriously though, does it even make sense to accept an answer to a `discussion`?

Comment: @Aldream it is up to you. Not accepting is fine and makes sense.

Comment: I really have **no** idea why this question is downvoted. This isn't a feature request, nor is it proselytizing an unpopular opinion. It's asking a genuine question which *many* new users have, one that doesn't seem to have a direct duplicate. At a minimum, I'd have thought the 3 people who considered it worthwhile to answer would upvote, but even that's not the case.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

No, it is not improper behavior.

It is fine if an OP can't and won't verify any longer for what ever reason if a solution works for them. In those cases it is even preferred they don't accept an answer. They, and no-one else either, can't tell if the answer worked best for them, which is what the accept vote means. Unverified answers shouldn't get that accept vote as it is a misleading signal to future visitors.

It is unfortunate an OP abandoned an problem but that is how life happens. If the question is interesting and your answer is any good you'll be rewarded plenty by upvotes from the community which is something you better strive for, instead of accept votes.

If anything improper it is begging for accept votes. An occasional comment won't hurt as long as the Q/A is active. I would not make it an habit to comment to users to review your answer or accept an answer. Those comments don't help to improve the content and should be removed by you or flagged as no longer needed (or what ever that comment flag option is called nowadays) if you come across them.

Addressing the additional issues raised:

> Shouldn't users be encouraged to provide minimal feedback once they open a new thread?

Sure, I assume the feedback is focussed on moderating the question so it is clear enough to be answered and understandable for future visitors. I like the metaphor Hans uses [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/372537/is-this-inproper-behavior-op-i-have-not-verified-the-solution-as-i-had-to/372538?noredirect=1#comment621046_372537). Establish shape and size of the hole that the OP has dug

> Should there be some discussion/moderation to prevent new threads bound to be abandoned, or should this be considered part of the system?

I can't imagine how that would work. Once an OP clicks Ask Question I assume they have something that might turnout interesting answers. If they are still interested in those, once they see the outcome is not something easily to determine. Offering them every 30 minutes a *click here if you're still interested in an answer* doesn't feel right. Once an answer is posted they do get an inbox message (and if they don't dismiss it they get an e-mail) so it won't go  unnoticed. If they accept / un-accept / re-accept over the life-time of the question is really up to them and I don't think extra nudges are needed. They either learn sooner or later what is needed from them or they are conscious about not accepting anything, ever (those users exist as well). Time will tell.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! As I tried to express in my post, I definitely agree that an answer should not be accepted unless tested and approved by OP, and getting your answer accepted should not be an end-goal. But as mentioned in the guidelines, shouldn't users be encouraged to provide minimal feedback once they open a new thread? Should there be some discussion/moderation to prevent _new_ threads bound to be abandoned, or should this be considered part of the system? I assume those are rather open questions, but I wonder what the current consensus is.

Comment: How would it be known in advance that a thread was _"bound to be abandoned"_?

Comment: @Turnip I roll the magic 8-ball ...

Comment: @Turnip If for instance a user has an unbroken streak of questions with at least one answer but no feedback (comment/edit/vote/...), chances the same will happen to the next question may be quite above average?

Comment: @Aldream that sounds like a number we used to show called [accept-rate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136951/lets-stop-displaying-a-users-accept-rate).

Comment: @rene Indeed, though I took good care not to include "accept" in my "feedback" list for such reason. I am also not so fond of public shaming, so I am definitely not arguing for some publicly-available metric.

Comment: Ah, the good-old-days of the "accept rate". I remember it well. For those that don't... https://i.stack.imgur.com/AvB9B.png

Answer (score 8):

> Are there *bad* reasons not to provide feedback?... If yes, what should one do to point this out?

**There are no *bad* reasons.** OP is within their rights to do something, or absolutely nothing, with the answer they receive. Initially, it's a sour pill to swallow for diligent answerers new to the SO Q&A framework. But soon you realise it's a blessing in disguise....

Q&A differentiates itself from a help-desk by being about the question, not about the questioner. The SO interface confuses people in this regard: an accepted answer shouldn't be pinned at the top, to reflect the fact the most helpful answer should be determined by voting alone.

The good news is that many users catch on to this anomaly and vote based on usefuleness. And upvotes are what generate reputation on SO, real and imaginary, in the long run.

I only ever ask if a question helped solve OP's problem when they are new and most likely unfamiliar with how SO works. This is a means of educating OP as well as a self-interested request for OP to consider accepting an answer.

Comment: I find this answer quite spot on, thanks! I do find the question/questioner dichotomy to be a really interesting and valid point. For the pure sake of arguing and pushing the discussion further, doesn't it however kind of contradict the "_be ready to try it out and provide feedback_" in the guidelines? Wouldn't the guidelines then just be about "_post a great question and let the community take it over_"?

Comment: I believe `be ready to try it out and provide feedback` is more advice to *questioners* to get most out of SO. I don't think it's directed at *answerers* or their expectations in any way.

Comment: Again, that's a good point. Thanks for the argumentation!

Answer (score 3):

> If someone posts an answer, be ready to try it out and provide feedback!

It does say that, but the first sentence in the paragraph says this:

> After you post, leave the question open in your browser for a bit, and see if anyone comments.

So the "be ready" part doesn't mean the OP is obligated to be able to test an answer forever, it means that the OP might get feedback on their question immediately after posting it. We know that users attempting to answer can get frustrated when the OP isn't around to give clarification and OPs aren't happy to come back to their question hours later only to find down and close votes on it and/or answers that indicate that their question was misunderstood. So the Help Center lets users know that they should be responsive right after posting when they're most likely to have people looking at it.

Note that the purpose of the page is:

> To improve your chances of getting an answer...

So while not doing some of what's on that page can lead to negative consequences, not everything there is punishable. For example, there's no close reason for putting the code before the description of a problem in a question.